# Estimating standard deviation in Poisson regression

Tags: regression, standard-deviation, poisson-distribution, generalized-linear-model

I'm interested in an estimator of the standard deviation in a Poisson regression. So the variance is

$$Var(y)=\phi\cdot V(\mu)$$

where $\phi=1$ and $V(\mu)=\mu$. So the variance should be $Var(y)=V(\mu)=\mu$. (I'm just interested in how the variance should be, so if overdispersion occurs ($\widehat{\phi}\neq 1$), I don't care about it). Thus an estimator of the variance should be

$$\widehat{Var}(y)=V(\widehat{\mu})=\widehat{\mu}$$

and an estimator of the standard deviation should be

$$\sqrt{\widehat{Var}(y)}=\sqrt{V(\widehat{\mu})}=\sqrt{\widehat{\mu}}.$$

Is this correct? I haven't found a discussion about standard deviation in the context with Poisson regression yet, that's why I'm asking.

**Example:**

So here is an easy example (which makes no sense btw) of what I'm talking about.

```
data1 <- function(x) {x^(2)}
numberofdrugs <- data1(1:84)
data2 <- function(x) {x}   
healthvalue <- data2(1:84)
plot(healthvalue, numberofdrugs)
test <- glm(numberofdrugs ~ healthvalue, family=poisson)
summary(test) #beta0=5.5 beta1=0.042
mu <- function(x) {exp(5.5+0.042*x)}
plot(healthvalue, numberofdrugs)
curve(mu,  add=TRUE, col="purple", lwd=2)
# the purple curve is the estimator for mu and it's also 
# the estimator of the variance,but if I'd like to plot 
# the (not constant) standard deviation I just take the 
# square root of the variance. So it is var(y)=mu=exp(Xb) 
# and thus the standard deviation is sqrt(exp(Xb))
sd <- function(x) {sqrt(exp(5.5+0.042*x))}
curve(sd, col="green", lwd=2)
```

Is the the green curve the correct estimator of the standard deviation in a Poisson regression? It should be, no?

Comment: Standard deviation of what?  In Poisson regression, $\mu$ varies with the independent variables.  Thus, unless the slope estimate is exactly zero, there is no fixed value of $\mu$.  Are you perhaps looking for some analog of the standard deviation of the regression residuals?

Comment: @whuber's point is valid. Please clarify. I am guessing you are trying to find the $\mu$? From a Bayesian perspective you can obtain a posterior distribution for $\mu | \mathbf{y}$.

Comment: you have 3 similar posts. Could you please give us a better picture of what your data are and what are you trying to answer. Standard deviation doesn't make a lot of sense. We want to know what's the S.D. for.

Comment: The follow-up Q was so similar that I've merged it with this.

Comment: First of all thank for the answers. I was thinking that my question was well formulated, but I'm willing to give you an example that should make clear of what I'm talking. So please look at the new open post: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12864/standard-deviation-when-estimating-a-poissonregression-using-r

Comment: @MarkDollar I've merged your two questions as the second one was merely an illustration for the present question. It's better to keep everything in the same thread.

Comment: Your reasoning looks fine to me @MarkDollar. This kind of "can you check i've got this right" question doesn't really make a great question for this site though.

Comment: Yes I know onestop, but since I havn't found something in any book about standard deviation using GLMs, I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: Do you want the _marginal_ standard deviation of $Y$ or the _conditional_ standard deviation $Y|\mu$? The latter is obviously not a single number, but a function of $\mu$ (which is in turn a function of your independent variables). It seems slightly funny to talk about "standard deviation" in Poisson regression because there's no such parameter in the model; unlike in Gaussian regression, the mean and the variance are inextricably coupled.

Comment: @jpillow I do not really understand your question. I'm just thinking about the estimated std deviation. Since $E(y)=Var(y)=\mu$, $\widehat{\mu}=exp(x\widehat\beta)$ should be the estimator for $E(y)$ and $Var(y)$ when using the can. link. So there is an estimator for the variance. Hence there should be an estimator for the standard deviation too, since the std deviation is just the squareroot of the variance. It's clear that neither the variance nor the std deviation are constant. For the std deviation it should be the green curve of my example above, which is $\sqrt{exp{(x\widehat{\beta)}}}$

Comment: @jpillow You could easily reparameterize the model to use $\mu^{1/2}$ instead of $\mu$; now it's parameterized by the standard deviation.  Moreover, since all these models are fit by ML, the ML estimate of $\mu^{1/2}$ is going to be the square root of the ML estimate of $\mu$.  In this new context it's perfectly natural to talk about the standard deviation rather than the mean.

Comment: @whuber: sure, you talk about it in any way you like. But I maintain it's still a strange thing to do, since the ML estimator for a Poisson R.V. is completely insensitive to variance/stdev.  (e.g., I could draw a wildly overdispersed sample with mean of 100 and variance of 400 (stdev of 20) and the Poisson ML estimate will converge to $\mu^{\frac{1}{2}}=10$, not $\mu^{\frac{1}{2}} = 20$). Since the sample mean is a sufficient statistic, it just seems slightly bizarre to call it an estimator for the standard deviation.

Comment: I realize it works out fine if the data actually _are_ Poisson. I suppose you _could_ get a (consistent, but non-Maximum Likelihood) estimate for $\mu^{\frac{1}{2}}$ using the square root of the sample variance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Poisson regression finds a value $\hat{\beta}$ maximizing the likelihood of the data.  For any value of $x$, you would then suppose $Y$ has a Poisson($\exp(x \hat{\beta})$) distribution.  The standard deviation of that distribution equals $\exp(x \hat{\beta}/2)$.  This appears to be what you mean by $\sqrt{\widehat{\mu}}$.

There are, of course, other ways to estimate the standard deviation of $Y|x$.  However, *staying within the context of Poisson regression,* $\exp(x \hat{\beta}/2)$ is the ML estimator of SD($Y|x$) for the simple reason that the ML estimator of a function of the parameters is the same function of the ML estimator of those parameters.  The function in this case is the one sending $\hat{\beta}$ to $\exp(x \hat{\beta}/2)$ (for any fixed value of $x$).  This theorem will appear in any full account of maximum likelihood estimation.  Its proof is straightforward.  Conceptually, the function is a way to re-express the parameters, but re-expressing them doesn't change the fact that they maximize (or fail to maximize, depending on their values) the likelihood.

Comment: That sounds good. Thus my guess was right.

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking too much in terms of "normally distributed" here.  For a normal distribution, you have two parameters then mean $\mu$ and the variance, $\sigma^2$.  So you require two pieces of information to characterize the probability distribution for the normal case.

However, in the Poisson distributed case, there is only one parameter, and that is the rate $\lambda$ (I relabeled to avoid confusion with normal).  This characterizes the Poisson distribution, and so there is no need to refer to other quantities.

This is why probably why don't hear standard deviation "estimation" mentioned in Poisson regression.  Asking for a standard deviation estimator for a Poisson random variable is analogous to asking for a kurtosis estimator for a normally distributed random variable.  You can get one, but why bother?  By estimating the rate parameter $\lambda$, you have all the information you need.

Comment: It is very interesting then that there exist several different kurtosis estimators for normal variables (all based on the *same* estimates of $\mu$ and $\sigma$)!  Do you suppose this could be what is motivating the original question? :-)

Comment: That there exists multiple estimators does not provide an answer to why one should try to "estimate" the kurtosis, given you have already estimated the mean and variance.  What value does it add, given we aren't questioning over-dispersion (as the OP stated)?

Comment: The point to keep in mind is that the O.P. is concerned about estimating a standard deviation and that there is no *a priori* reason to suppose the "obvious" estimator based on an estimated mean is best or even good.  Even though one parameter may characterize the Poisson and two may characterize the Normal distribution, that does not imply that estimators of those parameters solve all estimation problems involving those distributions!  (If it did, we could dispense with the entire theory of estimation...)

Comment: @probabilityislogic, I like the kurtosis analogy. (If you stipulate that you assume your sample is normal, there's nothing to estimate — the excess kurtosis is 0 by definition).  
@whuber, I'm intrigued by your answer: I was not aware of any estimators for kurtosis from normal RVs. (I can't fathom why one would want such a thing, except perhaps for a test of non-normality). Can you provide more intuition, or perhaps an example?

Comment: @whuber But at the moment, we have no reason to suppose that it is bad either.  And I am not referring to the absence of any indication of error in the estimate that is given to $\lambda$.  But the error in the estimate for $\lambda$ is not the same thing as the standard deviation.  From my perspective, if $\lambda$ was known with certainty, what is the use of a std dev estimator?  For normal, if mean is known, then standard deviation is still worth estimating.  But, if mean and std dev of a normal are known, what is the use of a kurtosis estimator?

Comment: @Prob But clearly $\lambda$ is being estimated via Poisson regression.  There's no issue when all parameters are known with certainty.  And just to be clear about a possible misunderstanding: we're not talking about the standard error of estimates.  We're talking about the standard deviation of a distribution whose parameters must be estimated from data.  There can be many reasons for a kurtosis estimator.  If you need one and you want it to be unbiased, for instance, you won't use the ML estimator or the moment estimator, you'll use something else.

Comment: @whuber - I see this as a problem with bias as a criterion of performance. A "best" estimator should be invariant, in the sense that $\hat{g}(\lambda)=g(\hat{\lambda})$ for a 1-to-1 function $g(x)$. And while there may be good reason in general for estimating kurtosis, I can't see a good one when the model isn't questioned (as is the case here). Same goes for standard deviation in poisson - unless you are interested in testing the assumptions of your model, only the estimate of the rate parameter matters. But the OP clearly states this is not his intention.

Comment: @Prob I brought up bias only as an example, not as a proposal that it be *the* criterion.  As you well know, there are a host of criteria, each suitable for different statistical problems.  Invariance under all functional transformations is a severe restriction, not enjoyed by many excellent estimators in common use: one could almost use it, I suspect, to characterize ML estimators.  And, again, kurtosis was something *you* brought up: in this conversation it has served as a proxy for any property of a distribution not identical to one of its parameters.

Comment: @whuber - and, once again - if the model is not being questioned, then why should we bother with anything except for its parameters, simply "plugging-in" for any estimates of functions of them

Comment: @whuber - invariance is not a severe restriction, if we understand that the loss function (or criterion) also changes when the parameter is transformed. If this doesn't occur, then one has implicitly changed what they mean by "best". I think the invariance you speak of is in terms of "unbiased" for $\hat{g}(\lambda)$ also means "unbiased" for $\hat{\lambda}$, which is not what I mean here (although you usually have approx unbiased).

Comment: @whuber - ML are not the only invariant estimators.  Any loss function which measure divergence between probability distributions will be invariant also.  One example is the KL divergence between the sampling dist with the true parameter, and the sampling distribution with the estimate plugged in.  $\int p(X|\theta)\log\left(\frac{p(X|\theta)}{p(X|\hat{\theta}(D))}\right)dX$.  This is the approach in bernardo's "Bayesian Reference Criterion".

Comment: @Prob Many thanks for those two comments on invariance.

Comment: @jpillow You asked about why one would want to estimate kurtosis for "normal variables." I agree that sounds strange. Your suggestion that it can be useful for normality tests is correct; many are based on skewness and kurtosis. In effect, these are simply *estimates* that, to give power to the tests that use them, should tend to be close to the values attained by normal variates when the data are normal. If one were to estimate a higher moment by first estimating the mean and SD, and then (assuming normality) compute that moment from the mean and SD, the resulting test would be worthless!